# Why doesn't the image path get saved in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, image

I'm trying to upload an image path along with some text to a MySQL database in PHP, how should I use the `move_uploaded_file` along with an SQL statement?

I've tried to move the `move_uploaded file` next to the statement. Though whatever I try, only the text will be saved in the database and not the image path. The code I have is this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['listpost-submit'])) {

$target = "site_images/";
$target2 = $target. basename($_FILES['image_file']['name']);

$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$cat = $_POST['categories'];
$vendor = $_POST['vendor'];

elseif (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['name'], $target2)) {
    //Database connection
    require 'dbh2.inc.php';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO listings 
(`image`,`title`,`description`,`price`,`category`,`vendor`) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: ../listing1.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
        }
        else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $image, $title, 
        $description, $price, $cat, $vendor);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        header("Location: ../index.php?listing=posted");
        exit();
         }
        }
        else {
    header("Location: ../listing1.php?file=notuploaded");
    exit();
         }
    }
    else {
        header("Location: ../listing1.php");
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

I expect all of my database columns to be filled with the given information but, the only thing missing is, of course, the image column and I want to know why that is.

Comment: You haven't defined `$image` anywhere from what I can see. Error-reporting would have informed you of this as well. :-)

Comment: What have you tried to spot the problem - any debugging attempts? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove that, I previously defined `$image` as `$_FILES`, that didn't work

Comment: `$image = $_FILES['image_file']['name']`. It must be defined somewhere before you can use it. :-) `$_FILES` is an array, not the name.

Comment: I'm new to debugging, how does that work with images or files?

Comment: Tried defining `$image`, file still isn't uploaded.

Comment: PD of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/845021) / ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](//stackoverflow.com/q/4261133)

Answer (score 0):

Used if name saved in the $image file

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image_file']['name'])
$image = $_FILES['image_file']['name'];
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your answer, tried that but still have no results?

Comment: I removed the exclamation mark and that does save the image path but not in the server directory

Answer (score 0):

In the form tag are you using `enctype='multipart/form-data'>"`?

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```